# The program works well but seems to be too slow for the test cases

Tags: arrays, c

I have this problem: You're given two arrays a1,a2,...,an and b1,b2,...,bn. In each step you can set ai = ai -bi if ai >= bi. Determine the minimum number of steps required to make all a's equal. If it's not possible, then print -1. [Problem Source](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/basic-programming/input-output/basics-of-input-output/practice-problems/algorithm/make-all-equal-90a21ab2/)

This is the program i wrote, but i got a Partially Accepted answer because the third test case exceeded the time limit.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// Check that all array's items are equal
int check_equality(const int *a, const int n);

int main (void) {
    int n = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int min = INT32_MAX;
    int max = 0;
    int steps = 0;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    int *a = calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    if (a == NULL) return 1;

    int *b = calloc(n, sizeof(int));
    if (b == NULL) return 1;
 
    // Reading data for a
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &a[i]);
        min = a[i] < min ? a[i] : min; // Getting min value in array
        max = a[i] > a[max] ? i : max; // Getting index of max value in array
    }

    // Reading data for b
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &b[i]);
    }

    // Counting for steps
    while(check_equality(a, n) != 0) {
        // When max number can't be reduced and
        // the array isn't equal print -1
        if (b[max] > a[max]) {
            steps = -1;
            break;
        }
        
        // Counting steps and rechecking if
        // min and max have changed
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            while(a[i] > min) {
                a[i] -= b[i];
                steps++;
            }
            min = a[i] < min ? a[i] : min;
            max = a[i] > a[max] ? i : max;
        }
    }

    free(a);
    free(b);

    printf("%d\n", steps);

    return 0;
}

int check_equality(const int *a, const int n)
{
    int i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        if (a[i] != a[i+1]) {
            return -1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I thoguht that the while loop was the problem and tried with these formulas:

```
steps += (a[i] - min) / b[i];
a[i] = min + ((a[i] - min) % b[i]);
```

But it only got worse. So i tried without using the check_equality function and use this condition instead:

```
while(min != max && a[max] > b[max])
```

But it didn't do it better. ¿What could i do to improve the performance of the program?

[image: Screenshot of results]

I've attached a screenshot of the results. It seems that the problem appears when it exceeds one second of execution.

Some test cases used:

```
5
5 7 10 5 15
2 2 1 3 5
Result: 8

2
5 6
4 3
Result: -1
```

I don't provide the third test case because it's an array of 5000 items and becomes too long to include here, but as a note, test cases 4, 5 and 6 also have 5000 items and work properly.

Comment: What is the third test case?

Comment: Lots of nested loops hints at O(n^2) or worse runtime complexity. This will lead to TLE messages on coding challenge sites.

Comment: @KenWhite I've already attached a link to the test cases and a screenshot of the results.

Comment: Your program loops forever if one of the b elements is zero.

Comment: We don't go off-site to get information needed for your question. It has to be here, in the question itself, so that it remains available for future site users. See [mre] and the [help/on-topic] for more information.

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you very much for your feedback. I've already added some plain test cases.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You got it! I wasn't keeping in mind that corner case. Thank you very much, i've solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program loops forever if one of the `b` elements is zero, and there is such an element in “Input #3”.